# RoR, Javascript - counter not working in #show action

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have created a 'create.js.erb' file which works fine to submit a form and show comments without refresh. But my comments count does not work.

My view:

```
   tweets/show.html.erb
    
  <div id="comment-count"><%= @comments.count %></div> Replies

  <div id="comment_pane">
    <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
      <%= render 'comments/comment', comment: comment %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

My JS

```
comments/create.js.erb

    $('#comment_pane').prepend('<%= j render @comment %>');
    $('#comment_body').val('');
    $('#comment-count').load(' #comment-count > *');
```

Prepending the comments and removing the value from the text area is fine but the count load won't show after submitting the form and I don't know why.

When I click reply the count goes blank.

Any guidance as to why my count might not be showing?

BTW the count does show updated if I just do this

```
$('#comment-count').load('#comment-count');
```

but the page doubles up with each click.

Comment: How about increase the comment count directly. Maybe something like this `$('#comment-count').text(parseInt($('#comment-count').text()) + 1))`

Comment: Yes, this works. I wonder why the other way does not? Strange.

Comment: @sam just checked this again, the count works but only for new replies. Even though there are 10 replies, for example, it says 0 until a new reply is added. How do I get the existing replies to show in the count?

Comment: Well, you can get all comments count in your rails controller, lets say you name it as `@comments_count`, and then in your create.js.erb `$('#comment-count').text(@comments_count)`

Comment: Thanks but doesn't work properly either. Maybe a syntax problem?